# how to display graphs using canvas element

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, html, graph-theory

While learning graph algorithms and canvas HTML element it stuck me that i should have a small graph library of my own in javascript which shows the graphs using canvas element can you point me in right direction so as i can read some code[js/python] as on how to display the graphs and write my own little lib.

PS : i mean edges and Node grapth not the bars and pie charts.

Comment: It *stuck* you that you should have this library and you went right to SO, to get it written for you? Also, what has Python got to do with this?

Comment: did i not mention that i intend to write it on my own , its just i wanted to have a look how other people have done it , i mentioned to imply that python because i can read up the code in python and then do my little version on js / canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to display graphs using various layout algorithms. Two of the primary ones are a Force-Directed layout algorithm, which can be a continuous layout algorithm using a push-pull principle. Next is the GEM layout algorithm which uses a rudimentary physics approach to determine the best "fit".

Here are some examples:

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html

bitbucket.org/bwalenz/algorithms/src/

Protovis has probably the most functional. The bitbucket link is an implementation of the GEM algorithm but with no visualization. It just lays out the nodes/edges.

Answer (score 2):

Not really using `canvas`, but quite a good JS solution for graphs: [**Raphael Charting plugin**](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

The good thing about Raphael is that it works in all browsers, IE included.

Comment: not the bar and pie charts what i meant is the node and edges graph.

Answer (score 1):

Great lib, for graphics in canvas: processing.js:
http://processingjs.org/
this is a graphic library, that allows you to write build amazing visualization using simple javascript code. have a look.